# Mobx react form confirm password issue

Tags: javascript, reactjs, mobx-react

I am using mobx-react-form (https://foxhound87.github.io/mobx-react-form/docs/getting-started-class.html) and I have a password rules validation like so, however the confirm password error comes up as soon as I tap outside of the confirm field regardless of the 2 values being exactly the same:

```
{
    name: 'changePassword',
    label: 'Change password',
    fields: [
        {
            name: 'password',
            label: t('user:Password'),
            rules: 'required|string|min:8',
            value: ''
        },
        {
            name: 'password2',
            label: t('user:Confirm password'),
            rules: 'required|string|same:password',
            value: ''
        }
    ]
},
```

as per the documentation this should work as expected.

[image]

Comment: Can you make a CodeSandbox and I'll take a look?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Didn't spot the fact that the change password section is nested:

```
{
    name: 'changePassword',
    label: 'Change password',
    fields: [
        {
            name: 'password',
            label: t('user:Password'),
            rules: 'required|string|min:8',
            value: ''
        },
        {
            name: 'password2',
            label: t('user:Confirm password'),
            rules: 'required|string|same:changePassword.password',
            value: ''
        }
    ]
},
```